# Join tables via multiple partial matching

Tags: r, join, dplyr

I have a table describing a train track with each line being a segment of the track with a `from` and `to` station as well as a `trackID` and `segment`-ID. The stations names are completely random, not as structured as they appear here.

```
tracks <- data.frame(
  trackID = c(rep("A",4),rep("B",4)),
  segment = letters[1:8],
  from = paste0("station_1",1:8),
  to = paste0("station_2",1:8)
  )

tracks 

  trackID segment       from         to
1       A       a station_11 station_21
2       A       b station_12 station_22
3       A       c station_13 station_23
4       A       d station_14 station_24
5       B       e station_15 station_25
6       B       f station_16 station_26
7       B       g station_17 station_27
8       B       h station_18 station_28
```

I have another table with sightings made on this train, and I would like to know what the correspoding `trackID` is per sighting. The table looks like this:

```
sightings <- data.frame(from = c("station_24","station_28","station_14"),
                    to = c("station_14","station_16","station_25"))

sightings 

        from         to
1 station_24 station_14
2 station_28 station_16
3 station_14 station_25
```

I *could* gather the information on the `trackID` from the `to` and `from`  information provided in the sightings table. BUT, `from` and `to` in the `sightings`-table do not correspond with the `from` and `to` in the `track`-table: `from` and `to` can be in different segments *and* can be interchanged (`to`-`from`). In some problematic cases, `from` and `to` are in different `trackID`, which would then return no match. The desired output from this example would be:

```
        from         to trackID
1 station_24 station_14       A
2 station_28 station_16       B
3 station_14 station_25    <NA> # no match since station_14 and 25 are from two different trackIDs
```

In my mind, the solution involves collapsing the `tracks` table by `trackID` and then doing a double partial matching of strings (using `grepl()`?). This next lines would take care of collapsing, but I have no clue where to go from here. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Solutions with `R` / `dplyr` very much preferred, but I would take anything!

```
library(dplyr)
tracks %>%
  group_by(trackID) %>%
  summarise(
    from_to = paste(paste(from,collapse = ","),paste(to,collapse = ","),sep = ",")
    )

tracks

trackID from_to                                                                                
  <fct>   <chr>                                                                                  
1 A       station_11,station_12,station_13,station_14,station_21,station_22,station_23,station_24
2 B       station_15,station_16,station_17,station_18,station_25,station_26,station_27,station_28
```

**EDIT:** It seems that I've oversimplified my problem in my minimal example. The main issue is that stations (`from` and `to`) are not unique in the table, and not even unique to a `trackID`. Only a *combination* of `to` and `from` is unique to a `trackID`. I've accepted the answer as it solves the problem as stated, but I will also provide my own solution that I've come up with in the meantime.

Comment: Other than possibly sourcing the data from a SQL database, do you really need the `[sql]` and `[postgresql]` tags?

Comment: I meant to declare that I'm open to SQL postgreSQL solutions, as I've stated in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A double-join can work.

Notes: You don't appear to be using `segment`, so I'm discarding it here, but this might be adapted if needed. Also, I added `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` to your data, since otherwise combining vectors of `factor`s can be problematic.)

```
library(dplyr)

tracksmod <- bind_rows(
  select(tracks, trackID, sta=from),
  select(tracks, trackID, sta=to)
)
head(tracksmod)
#   trackID        sta
# 1       A station_11
# 2       A station_12
# 3       A station_13
# 4       A station_14
# 5       B station_15
# 6       B station_16

sightings %>%
  left_join(select(tracksmod, trackID, from=sta), by="from") %>%
  left_join(select(tracksmod, trackID2=trackID, to=sta), by="to") %>%
  mutate(trackID = if_else(trackID == trackID2, trackID, NA_character_)) %>%
  select(-trackID2)
#         from         to trackID
# 1 station_24 station_14       A
# 2 station_28 station_16       B
# 3 station_14 station_25    <NA>
```

I did not assume that directionality was important. That is, I'm not assuming that a station listed in `from` must always be in the `from` column. This is why I converted `tracks` to `tracksmod`, in order to identify a station with an id regardless of direction.

Comment: Could also have used `tracksmod <- tidyr::gather(tracks, dir, sta, -segment) %>% select(-segment)`

Answer (score 0):

As I've stated in the EDIT of my question, I've oversimplified my problem in the minimal Example. 
Here is an updated version of the data that resembles my data more accurately. I've also added `stringsAsFactor = F` as commented by @r2evans.

```
tracks <- data.frame(
  trackID = c(rep("A",4),rep("B",4)),
  segment = letters[1:8],
  from = paste0("station_1",c(1:4,1,2,5,6)),
  to = paste0("station_2",1:8),
  stringsAsFactors = F
  )

sightings <- data.frame(
  from = c("station_24","station_28","station_14"),
  to = c("station_14","station_11","station_25"),
  trackID = c("A","B",NA),
  stringsAsFactors = F
)
```

I've solved the problem by collapsing the `tracks` table on the basis of `trackID` and then using the `purrr` package to use the loop functions in a nested manner.

```
library(dplyr)

# Collapsing the tracks-dataframe
tracks_collapse <- tracks %>%
  group_by(trackID) %>%
  summarise(
    from_to = paste(paste(from,collapse = ","),paste(to,collapse = ","),sep = ",")
    # from = list(from),
    # to = list(to),
    # stas = list(c(from,to))
    )

# a helper function to remove NAs when looking for matches
remove_na <- function(x){x[!is.na(x)]}

library(purrr)


pmap_dfr(sightings, function(from,to,trackID){                         # pmap_dfr runs over a data.frame and returns a data.frame
  data.frame(
    from = from,                                                       # recreates the sightings data.frame
    to = to,                                                           # dito
    trackID = paste(                                                   # collapses the resulting vector
      remove_na(                                                       # removes the NA values
        pmap_chr(                                                      # matches every row from the sightings-data.frame with the tracks-data.frame
          tracks_collapse,
          function(trackID,from_to){
            ifelse(grepl(from,from_to) & grepl(to,from_to),trackID,NA) # does partial string matching and returns the trackID if both strings match
            }
          )
        ),collapse = ","
      )
    )
  })
```

Output:

```
        from         to trackID
1 station_24 station_14       A
2 station_28 station_11       B
3 station_14 station_25    <NA>
```